# How to avoid require(..\..\src\test) using NODE_PATH in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I replace long relative file paths like `require(..\..\src\test)` with the more convenient notation `require(src\test)`?

I try the solution of `NODE_PATH` in package.json following this article: https://www.coreycleary.me/escaping-relative-path-hell/

but when run `npm start`, I get a 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' error.

My package.json look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=/src/zip && node index.js"
  },
```

I work in a windows environment and get the error `'NODE_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

Comment: You need to remove the "`&&`" in your `start` command. The environment variable `NODE_PATH` is only read into your node script if it's passed in the same command. That "&&" creates two different commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually replace the path before \src\test with `/*$__dirname$*/` and then read the JSON file from your node application, and replace `/*$__dirname$*/` with the value of the `__dirname` JavaScript variable.

So do this before creating the server or listening to it.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonFilePath = '<path>';

// Read the json file
let json = fs.readFileSync(jsonFilePath, 'utf-8');

if(json.includes('/*$__dirname$*/')) {
    // Replace /*$__dirname$*/ with the variable __dirname's value
    json = json.replace('/*$__dirname$*/', __dirname);
    
    // Change the JSON file text
    fs.writeFile('jsonFilePath', json, (err) => {
        if(err) { console.log(err); }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this without changing any `process.env` variables.

You can use the `package.json` `exports` field. More information about this is on the [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_self_referencing_a_package_using_its_name). The `exports` field can be used to define exported files and directories. For example, if your package name is `my-package` and you want to make the `/deep/deeper/src/` folder available as just `my-package/src`, you can use the `exports` field.

Example:

Files:

```
deep/
    deeper/
        src/
            test.js
            more.js
package.json
index.js
```

`package.json` content:

```
{
    "name": "my-module"
    "exports": {
        ".": "./index.js"
        "./src/": "./deep/deeper/src"
    }
}
```

**Note: The `/` after `./src` tells node that it's for everything in `/src/`, not just a file named `/src`.**

`index.js` content:

```js
//Self referencing the module is allowed if you use --experimental-modules flag.
require("my-package/src/test");

//This is the 'hell' that you would be avoiding.
require("./deep/deeper/src/test");
```

I like this solution because you can specify many different paths and files just by changing `package.json`. The files in the module can refer their own package which [this section of the docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_self_referencing_a_package_using_its_name) explains.

**Note: Depending on the version of node you are using, you might need to use the `--exerimental-modules` flag. For example:**

```sh
node --experimental-modules index.js
```